# NoClassDefFoundError exception in pdf generation in Grails

Tags: java, exception, grails, plugins, pdf-generation

In my Grails application, I use pdf plugin to create pdfs.
When I try to create a pdf, the following exception is raised:

```
there was a problem with PDF generation java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11FontManager
```

What can be the cause of this exception for this particular case?
Notice that the machine has 1.7.0_45 version of Java and I am using Ubuntu with UI.

EDIT:
I've tried with another machine with Java 1.7.0_17 and it works. Are there maybe differences between the two versions of Java or it depends on differences between Ubuntu versions?

EDIT 2:
I've tried to run Java in headless mode, but I have another exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/jdk1.7.0_60/jre/lib/i386/libfontmanager.so: libgcc_s.so.1
```

Is the only solution to run a previous working Java version (like the 1.7.0_17), or is it possible to solve it in another way?

Comment: Are you using openjdk by any chance?

Comment: No, I've checked with the command update-alternatives --config java and Java is used

Comment: Which Java - openjdk or oracle jdk?

Comment: Sorry, I mean Oracle jdk

Comment: Have you considered running the jre in headless Mode?

Comment: The fact is that, in development machine, the plugin works well. And I use the 1.7.0_17 version of Oracle Java...what about headless mode?

Comment: If Java runs on a machine without active gui, it should be configured headless. Otherwise it tries to access gui resources in its awt classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error typically occurs when using AWT classes while running in a non-gui environment (ie. Linux server without X11 installed).  You can force Java to run in "Headless mode" with a JVM option:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

This is something you can add to the GRAILS_OPTS environment variable, used by `grails run-app`.  Or, if you're running under Tomcat or similar, this JVM option can be added to your startup script.

Comment: As in my post, I'm using Ubuntu with UI...so maybe there is some lack in Java version?

Comment: Besides to Andrew suggestion, it is needed to install libgcc_s.so.1.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned many times the NoClassDefFoundError means that a class in your classpath missed another class (from which it is dependent).

In other words you have the class A that depends on class B, but in your classpath you have class A only. So you can compile without problem, but at runtime JVM can't find class B, which is needed to get class A working

Comment: I clearly understand about why the exception is raised in general, but I need to know about the cause in this particular case...and resolve it;)

Comment: Andrew's answer could be a good hipotesis. If you're on a linux machine without UI you may encounter that problem. Which PDF framework stands beside grail plugin? I encountered same problem with iText